# Invalid character in MVC 4 Web API template Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I try to create an **MVC 4 Web API project** in Visual Studio 2012 Express Web edition, but I get an error : **'.' hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1 position 1.** This is a translation from french so it might not be the exact same thing in english. The popup error message pops at the end of the project creation. The project is created, but the FilterConfig.cs and RouteConfig.cs are empty. So it doesn't compile.

When I use the Internet Application template instead of the Web API, I do get the same error, but this time, it's the HomeController.cs that is empty. Anyone knows what I should do ?

Comment: Seems like an issue with the project templates - could try uninstalling and reinstalling MVC4?

Comment: I did reinstall all VS 2012 and it worked after that.